# Sorting Vader Sentiment Analysis Results in Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nlp, nltk

Is there a commonly used method for sorting multiple Vader Sentiment Analysis Results in Dictionary

**I am trying to sort by 'compound' Vader Sentiment Analysis Results in the review Dictionary.**

I just started learning nlp and Sentiment Analysis and got my first project to 95% so far been learning books, tutorials and here.

I was hoping to **sort closest scores 5 overall sentiments scores** to a particular one in a large set of multiple dictionary results.

**this what i tried**
Might be also due to printing it being a string I assume i need to convert this to string or object, just not sure next steps.I was think I might need to loop through dictionary or convert the dictionary. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
newlist = sorted(review, key=lambda k: k['compound'])
```

[image: Error screenshot]

**I also tried**

```
from operator import itemgetter
newlist = sorted(review, key=itemgetter('compound'))
```

[image]

**The Vader results are printed from dictionary.**

```
s = pprint.pformat(review)
print(s)
```

**This is the format of the results which i think is standard output**

```
 'america-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.051, 'neu': "
                    "0.632, 'pos': 0.316, 'compound': 1.0}, sentence was rated "
                    'as 5.1% Negative, sentence was rated as 63.2% Neutral, '
                    'sentence was rated as 31.6% Positive, Sentence Overall '
                    'Rated As Positive',
 'amygrant-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.022, 'neu': "
                     "0.734, 'pos': 0.244, 'compound': 0.9998}, sentence was "
                     'rated as 2.1999999999999997% Negative, sentence was '
                     'rated as 73.4% Neutral, sentence was rated as 24.4% '
                     'Positive, Sentence Overall Rated As Positive',
 'andygarcia-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': "
                       "0.955, 'pos': 0.045, 'compound': 0.8419}, sentence was "
                       'rated as 0.0% Negative, sentence was rated as 95.5% '
                       'Neutral, sentence was rated as 4.5% Positive, Sentence '
                       'Overall Rated As Positive',
 'annemurray-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.02, 'neu': "
                       "0.769, 'pos': 0.211, 'compound': 0.9986}, sentence was "
                       'rated as 2.0% Negative, sentence was rated as 76.9% '
                       'Neutral, sentence was rated as 21.099999999999998% '
                       'Positive, Sentence Overall Rated As Positive',
 'annielennox-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.03, "
                        "'neu': 0.717, 'pos': 0.254, 'compound': 0.9999}, "
                        'sentence was rated as 3.0% Negative, sentence was '
                        'rated as 71.7% Neutral, sentence was rated as 25.4% '
                        'Positive, Sentence Overall Rated As Positive',
 'artgarfunkel-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.056, "
                         "'neu': 0.642, 'pos': 0.302, 'compound': 1.0}, "
                         'sentence was rated as 5.6000000000000005% Negative, '
                         'sentence was rated as 64.2% Neutral, sentence was '
                         'rated as 30.2% Positive, Sentence Overall Rated As '
                         'Positive',
 'bangles-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.054, 'neu': "
                    "0.733, 'pos': 0.213, 'compound': 0.9998}, sentence was "
                    'rated as 5.4% Negative, sentence was rated as 73.3% '
                    'Neutral, sentence was rated as 21.3% Positive, Sentence '
                    'Overall Rated As Positive',
 'barbrastriesand-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.014, "
                            "'neu': 0.815, 'pos': 0.171, 'compound': 0.9982}, "
                            'sentence was rated as 1.4000000000000001% '
                            'Negative, sentence was rated as 81.5% Neutral, '
                            'sentence was rated as 17.1% Positive, Sentence '
                            'Overall Rated As Positive',
 'barrymanilow-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.041, "
                         "'neu': 0.647, 'pos': 0.313, 'compound': 1.0}, "
                         'sentence was rated as 4.1000000000000005% Negative, '
                         'sentence was rated as 64.7% Neutral, sentence was '
                         'rated as 31.3% Positive, Sentence Overall Rated As '
                         'Positive',
 'beachboys-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.016, 'neu': "
                      "0.906, 'pos': 0.078, 'compound': 0.945}, sentence was "
                      'rated as 1.6% Negative, sentence was rated as '
                      '90.60000000000001% Neutral, sentence was rated as 7.8% '
                      'Positive, Sentence Overall Rated As Positive',
 'belindacarlisle-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.046, "
                            "'neu': 0.756, 'pos': 0.197, 'compound': 0.9987}, "
                            'sentence was rated as 4.6% Negative, sentence was '
                            'rated as 75.6% Neutral, sentence was rated as '
                            '19.7% Positive, Sentence Overall Rated As '
                            'Positive',
 'bernadettepeters-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.02, "
                             "'neu': 0.753, 'pos': 0.227, 'compound': 0.9992}, "
                             'sentence was rated as 2.0% Negative, sentence '
                             'was rated as 75.3% Neutral, sentence was rated '
                             'as 22.7% Positive, Sentence Overall Rated As '
                             'Positive',
 'bethhart-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.041, 'neu': "
                     "0.592, 'pos': 0.366, 'compound': 1.0}, sentence was "
                     'rated as 4.1000000000000005% Negative, sentence was '
                     'rated as 59.199999999999996% Neutral, sentence was rated '
                     'as 36.6% Positive, Sentence Overall Rated As Positive',
 'bettemidler-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.043, "
                        "'neu': 0.635, 'pos': 0.322, 'compound': 0.9999}, "
                        'sentence was rated as 4.3% Negative, sentence was '
                        'rated as 63.5% Neutral, sentence was rated as 32.2% '
                        'Positive, Sentence Overall Rated As Positive',
 'bjork-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.042, 'neu': "
                  "0.696, 'pos': 0.262, 'compound': 1.0}, sentence was rated "
                  'as 4.2% Negative, sentence was rated as 69.6% Neutral, '
                  'sentence was rated as 26.200000000000003% Positive, '
                  'Sentence Overall Rated As Positive',
 'bluemangroup-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.047, "
                         "'neu': 0.726, 'pos': 0.227, 'compound': 0.9999}, "
                         'sentence was rated as 4.7% Negative, sentence was '
                         'rated as 72.6% Neutral, sentence was rated as 22.7% '
                         'Positive, Sentence Overall Rated As Positive',
 'bluetravelers-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.0, "
                          "'neu': 0.914, 'pos': 0.086, 'compound': 0.9455}, "
                          'sentence was rated as 0.0% Negative, sentence was '
                          'rated as 91.4% Neutral, sentence was rated as 8.6% '
                          'Positive, Sentence Overall Rated As Positive',
 'bobbyvinton-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': "
                        "0.928, 'pos': 0.072, 'compound': 0.9501}, sentence "
                        'was rated as 0.0% Negative, sentence was rated as '
                        '92.80000000000001% Neutral, sentence was rated as '
                        '7.199999999999999% Positive, Sentence Overall Rated '
                        'As Positive',
 'bonnieRatt-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.034, "
                       "'neu': 0.612, 'pos': 0.354, 'compound': 0.9999}, "
                       'sentence was rated as 3.4000000000000004% Negative, '
                       'sentence was rated as 61.199999999999996% Neutral, '
                       'sentence was rated as 35.4% Positive, Sentence Overall '
                       'Rated As Positive',
 'boygeorge-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.039, 'neu': "
                      "0.884, 'pos': 0.076, 'compound': 0.9217}, sentence was "
                      'rated as 3.9% Negative, sentence was rated as 88.4% '
                      'Neutral, sentence was rated as 7.6% Positive, Sentence '
                      'Overall Rated As Positive',
 'brianlittrell-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.052, "
                          "'neu': 0.873, 'pos': 0.074, 'compound': 0.8203}, "
                          'sentence was rated as 5.2% Negative, sentence was '
                          'rated as 87.3% Neutral, sentence was rated as '
                          '7.3999999999999995% Positive, Sentence Overall '
                          'Rated As Positive',
 'briansetzerorchestra-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': "
                                 "0.046, 'neu': 0.646, 'pos': 0.308, "
                                 "'compound': 1.0}, sentence was rated as 4.6% "
                                 'Negative, sentence was rated as '
                                 '64.60000000000001% Neutral, sentence was '
                                 'rated as 30.8% Positive, Sentence Overall '
                                 'Rated As Positive',
 'brianwilson-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.042, "
                        "'neu': 0.647, 'pos': 0.311, 'compound': 1.0}, "
                        'sentence was rated as 4.2% Negative, sentence was '
                        'rated as 64.7% Neutral, sentence was rated as 31.1% '
                        'Positive, Sentence Overall Rated As Positive',
 'brucehornsby-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.0, "
                         "'neu': 0.928, 'pos': 0.072, 'compound': 0.9196}, "
                         'sentence was rated as 0.0% Negative, sentence was '
                         'rated as 92.80000000000001% Neutral, sentence was '
                         'rated as 7.199999999999999% Positive, Sentence '
                         'Overall Rated As Positive',
 'bryanadams-reviews': "Overall sentiment dictionary is : {'neg': 0.008, "
                       "'neu': 0.933, 'pos': 0.059, 'compound': 0.9028}, "
                       'sentence was rated as 0.8% Negative, sentence was '
                       'rated as 93.30000000000001% Neutral, sentence was '
                       'rated as 5.8999999999999995% Positive, Sentence '
                       'Overall Rated As Positive',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct sorting doesn't work because your dictionary values are strings, not dictionaries or lists. To sort by compound you need to extract it's value at first. Here is a simple example of how you can do it by using regex and lambda:

```py
import re


def extract_compound(item):
    # define regex to extract compound value
    rgxp = r'(?<=\'compound\':\s)\d\.\d+'
    compound = re.search(rgxp, item)
    compound = compound.group(0)

    return float(compound)


review_sorted = {key: value for key, value in sorted(
    review.items(), key=lambda item: extract_compound(item[1]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I got a error but I assume I just need to figure out that regex pattern to get it work.    review.items(), key=lambda item: extract_compound(item[1]), reverse=True)
                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Regex should be ok, I tested it using your posted data as a dictionary. However, there may be different situations, patterns in your full data, so in that case you need to change regex accordingly or add additional checks to validate data, for example, if there are None values and handle it.

Comment: thanks again, oh yeah the none values its most likely that i didn't handle that yet,  i will fill the nan values first and try again